# Linear cx scaling with javascript objects in D3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am attempting to plot a simple dataset consisting of an array of javascript objects. Here is the array in JSON format.

```
[{"key":"FITC","count":24},{"key":"PERCP","count":16},{"key":"PERCP-CY5.5","count":16},{"key":"APC-H7","count":1},{"key":"APC","count":23},{"key":"APC-CY7","count":15},{"key":"ALEXA700","count":4},{"key":"E660","count":1},{"key":"ALEXA647","count":17},{"key":"PE-CY5","count":4},{"key":"PE","count":38},{"key":"PE-CY7","count":18}]
```

Each object simply contains a `String: "key"`, and a `Integer: "count"`.

Now, I am plotting these in D3 as follows.

```
    function key(d) {
      return d.key;
    }

    function count(d) {
      return parseInt(d.count);
    }

    var w = 1000,
    h = 300,
    //x = d3.scale.ordinal()
          //.domain([count(lookup)]).rangePoints([0,w],1);
    //y = d3.scale.ordinal()
          //.domain(count(lookup)).rangePoints([0,h],2);

    var svg = d3.select(".chart").append("svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h);

    var abs = svg.selectAll(".little")
                .data(lookup)
                .enter().append("circle")
                .attr("cx", function(d,i){return ((i + 0.5)/lookup.length) * w;})
                .attr("cy", h/2).attr("r", function(d){ return d.count * 1.5})
```

[Here is what this looks like thus far.](http://s28.postimg.org/bprdmjb6l/circles.jpg)

What I am concerned about is how I am mapping my "cx" coordinates. Shouldn't the x() scaling function take care of this automatically, as opposed to scaling as I currently handle it? I've also tried .attr("cx", function(d,i){return x(i)}).

What I eventually want to do is label these circles with their appropriate "keys". Any help would be much appreciated.

**Update:**

I should mention that the following worked fine when I was dealing with an array of only the counts, as opposed to an array of objects:

```
x = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(nums).rangePoints([0, w], 1),
y = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(nums).rangePoints([0, h], 2);
```

Comment: you're mentioning linear scale in the heading but ordinal scale appears in your code. did you mean otherwise?

Comment: Thanks, I had been experimenting with both, neither seemed to be having an effect on scaling my code. As of now, neither of the scales is being used to manipulate the objects. I commented them out in the selection. @EliranMalka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is doing what you want...I just added the text part. Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/58uc4/).

```
var txt = svg.selectAll(".txt")
    .data(lookup)
    .enter().append("text")
    .attr("x", function (d, i) {
        return ((i + 0.5) / lookup.length) * w;
    })
    .attr("y", h / 2)
    .text(function(d) {return d.key;});
```

I commented out the scales, they were not being used...as already noted by you.

Comment: It looks better with text anchored to the center. [UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/58uc4/1/).

Comment: Thank you, the text part is helpful. You are correct in that the code is doing what I want, although I would prefer to just scale them by their index, as opposed to doing a manual "hacky" way! This way that scale bit could also be used for text positioning.

Comment: Gotcha...missed the point that you wanted to use scales...when i come back later, i can work on it, unless somebody does it in the meantime...it is not complicated.

Comment: I suppose what I could do is add an index to the object when it is generated, simply scaling by this. Though I feel like this again defeats the purpose of D3 scaling :)

Comment: @lennart I worked on a simple x-scale for you. See [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/58uc4/2/).